# Some Ecosmart bulbs burn bright some do not

Tags: lighting

I live in a condo built in 1968.  One building has 12 one bedrooms and two long halls with 7 lights in each hall.  These lights have a glass cover so there is no air circulation to the bulb.  We found that the electric wires insulation was brittle because the 60w bulbs we used were so hot.  We changed to Ecosmart 60w LED soft white, A19, non-dimmable lasts 10 years 11,000 hours.  On the box it says suitable for use in enclosed fixtures, which is what we have.  We replaced all of the 14 bulbs and they all burn bright except three.  The man that put them in said they flickered bright then went dim when he put them in the fixture.  After working one day and night I took another bulb and replaced the one that was dim the new bulb flickered bright then dim.  I took the bulb  I took out and put it in a lamp in my unit and it burned bright. When I replaced the light bulb the bulb was not hot and neither was the glass cover.  This is just what we wanted to accomplish except for the three bulbs that will not burn bright. All of the other eleven bulbs are ok and suggestions?  Bob Law

Comment: With power off, would check those fixtures for loose connections and make sure the centre is still making good contact with the bulbs.  Was the brittle insulation repaired/replaced?

Comment: FYI the new lamps are 60w equivalent only about 9w actual but this depends on the brand and efficiency. A volt meter would be needed to take the circuit values anything else is going to be a guess like a bad connection in a daisy chain since it only affects 3.